# without wrapping jQuery search result

Tags: jquery

ASP.NET is changing id, name values according to control's parent control name. That's why i am searching id with JQUERY as below.

```
// $ is looking to the end of "id" attribute of input elements
$("input[id$='cbAddToNews']")
```

Only one element is returning by jQuery. But when i want to change the attribute, I'm using this syntax:

```
$($("input[id$='cbAddToNews']")[0]).show()
```

Is there any way to do this without wrapping it with `$(...[0])` ?

Answer (score 1):

You should rather find out the actual ID being assigned to it via the `ClientID` property instead of using `$=`.

Also, if jQuery is already only returning one element, why do you try to limit it to the first one separately?

Answer (score 1):

You can use classes instead. Assign a class to your ASP.NET element using *CssClass="classname"*.

use *$('input.classname')* to select the element in jQuery.